# Find a function $g(x,y)$ harmonic on $\{ 1<x^2+y^2<16\}$ such that...

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

In reviewing complex analysis, I stumbled upon the following problem:

> Find a function $g(x,y)$ harmonic on $\{ 1<x^2+y^2<16\}$ such that $g(x,y)=3$ when $x^2+y^2=1$ and $g(x,y)=8$ when $x^2+y^2=16$.

In my notebook, I saw some notes on the side that $g(x,y)$ should have the form $a \cdot \ln(x^2+y^2)+b$, but not only am I unsure of how to derive this equation- I'm not certain it's correct to begin with.

I know that in the standard Cartesian plane, a Harmonic function is one that satisfies Laplace's equation, that is, that the sum of the second partial derivatives is $0$.

Where to proceed from here, however, I am unsure.

Comment: One can substitute the specific values given in the question in the general form mentioned to give a linear system of equations for $a, b$.

Comment: @Travis Certainly, hence why we're given two constraints (i.e., $g=3$ when $x^2+y^2=1$ and $g=8$ when $x^2+y^2=16$). I'm unsure on the form of $g(x,y)$ though- or at least, deriving it

Answer (score 2):

In cylindrical coordinates, let $ g(\rho ,\phi)$ be harmonic in the region $1<\rho<4$.  Then, $g(\rho,\phi)$ satisfies Laplace's Equation

$$\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial }{\partial \rho}\left(\rho \frac{\partial  g}{\partial \rho}\right)+\frac{1}{\rho^2}\frac{\partial^2  g}{\partial \phi^2}=0$$

with $g(1,\phi)=3$ and  $g(4,\phi)=8$.

Symmetry suggests that $g$ is independent of $\phi$ and the problem reduces to an ordinary differential equation

$$\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{d }{d\rho}\left(\rho \frac{d  g}{d \rho}\right)=0 \tag 1$$

Integrating $(1)$, we find that $g(\rho)=A\log(\rho)+B$.  Enforcing the boundary conditions, we have $g(1)=B=3$ and $g(4)=A\log(4)+3=8\implies A=\frac{5}{\log(4)}$.  Therefore, the solution is

$$g(\rho)=\frac{5\log(\rho)}{\log(4)}+3$$

Comment: That looks good, but I'm not certain how you got $$\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial }{\partial \rho}\left(\rho \frac{\partial  g}{\partial \rho}\right)+\frac{1}{\rho^2}\frac{\partial^2  g}{\partial \phi^2}=0.$$ Pardon if my confusion seems elementary; it's been a little while since I've done some of this

Comment: Actually, I'm not really sure how you integrated, either- with respect to which variable?

Comment: There is only one variable.